# JPGraph on Raspberry Pi: Problems with X-Axis: Own Timestamp won't accepted

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi, axis, jpgraph

currently I'm working on a study project. We have a weather station which gives us data for wind direction and speed. Those data is saved in a mysql-database incl timestamp.
Now I want to publish those data on a website using jpgraph.
Adding the y-axis was no problem. But now I want to use my timestamps as x-axis.
Somehow I'm not able to get it to work. I've read dozens tutorials to get it to work but failed.
Here is my code.

```
<?php
include('./structure.php'); // contains the HTML-Start
include('./speedGraph.php');
include('./debugFunc.php');
echo "<div id='content'>";
echo "<h2>Graphischer Verlauf</p></h2>";

$dbInstanz = mysql_connect('192.168.137.42', 'pi', 'raspberry');
if (!$dbInstanz) {
    die('Verbindung schlug fehl: ' . mysql_error());
}
/*    if(dbInstanz)
{
    echo 'Erfolgreich verbunden';

}*/
$dbInstanz_selected = mysql_select_db('wetterstation', $dbInstanz);
if (!$dbInstanz_selected) {
    die ('Kann windanlage nicht benutzen : ' . mysql_error());
}


// read DB
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `windstaerke` LIMIT 100";
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $dbInstanz );
$countOfData = mysql_num_rows($result);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
//Datenarrays
$Timestamp;
$meterProSec;
$beaufort;
$i = 0;

if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

     $Timestamp[$i] = $row['time'];
     $meterProSec[$i] = $row['meterProSec'];
     $beaufort[$i] = $row['beaufort'];

    $i++;
}
//echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

//GRAPH


drawGraph($Timestamp,$meterProSec,$beaufort, $TimestampLabels,countOfData); //calls the second php in this post
echo "<img src='./Graph/windstaerke.png'>";

echo "</div>";



mysql_close($dbInstanz);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code delivers the DB-data.
Now I want to create a graph.

```
<?php
require_once('./jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php');
require_once('./jpgraph/src/jpgraph_line.php');
require_once('./jpgraph/src/jpgraph_utils.inc.php');
require_once( "jpgraph/src/jpgraph_date.php" );
function debug_to_console( $data ) {

if ( is_array( $data ) )
    $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . implode( ',', $data) . "' );</script>";
else
    $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $data . "' );</script>";

echo $output;
}

function drawGraph($timestamp, $meterProSec, $beaufort, $timestampLabels, $CountOfData)
{

//Erforderliche Daten zum Handling in andre Varariablen kopieren
$datax1 = $timestamp;
$datay1 = $meterProSec;
$datay2 = $beaufort;

//Graph konfigurieren und erstellen
$dateUtils = new DateScaleUtils();
debug_to_console($sizeDatax1);
list($tickPositions, $minTickPositions) = $dateUtils->GetTicks($datax1);
$grace = 4;
$xmin = $datax1[0] - $grace;
$xmax = $datax1[$CountOfData - 1] + $grace;

$graph = new Graph(800,500);
$graph->SetScale( 'datlin',0,17 );

$graph->title->Set('Verlauf der herrschenden Windstaerke');
$graph->xaxis->SetPos('min');

$yMeterProSec = new LinePlot($datay1);
$graph->Add($yMeterProSec);
$ybeaufort = new LinePlot($datay2);
$graph->Add($ybeaufort);

//Datenlinien definieren (Farben etc)
$yMeterProSec->SetColor("#55bbdd");
$yMeterProSec->SetLegend('Meter/Sekunde');
$yMeterProSec->mark->SetColor('#55bbdd');
$yMeterProSec->mark->SetFillColor('#55bbdd');
$yMeterProSec->SetCenter();

$ybeaufort->SetColor("#aaaaaa");
$ybeaufort->SetLegend('Beaufort');
$ybeaufort->mark->SetColor('#aaaaaa');
$ybeaufort->mark->SetFillColor('#aaaaaa');
$ybeaufort->value->SetMargin(14);
$ybeaufort->SetCenter();

//X-Achse Skalieren
$graph->xaxis->scale->SetTimeAlign(DAYADJ_1);
$graph->xaxis->scale->SetDateFormat( 'H:i' );

$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($timestamp);
//graph->xaxis->SetTextLabelInterval(10); // Nur alle x Werte anzeigen
//$graph->xaxis->SetTickPositions($tickPositions,$minTickPositions);
//$graph->xaxis->SetLabelFormat('%0.1f%%');
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(90);
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelMargin(2);

//Legende
$graph->legend->Pos(0.05,0.1);
$graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(1);
$graph->legend->SetColor('#4E4E4E','#00A78A');
$graph->legend->SetMarkAbsSize(8);
$lineplot = new LinePlot($datay2);
$graph->AddY2($lineplot);

unlink('./Graph/windstaerke.png');
$graph->Stroke('./Graph/windstaerke.png');
}
?>
```

This code prints the data but it is not able to use my x-axis data as x-axis for my y data. Some posts on google say I have to convert die data with something like this

```
//Format Date
function formatDate(&$aVal) {
$aVal = date('Y-m-d H:i',$aVal);
}

array_walk($timestamp,'formatDate');
```

But this does not work for me...

Can somebody help me... I do not have any idead anymore...
How can I use my db-data as x axis ?

This is how my graph looks like right now...(Can't insert an image.. so it's a link)

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTBsJ.png)

Thanks
minni